# Evince is slow to open (on overlayroot with apparmor disabled)

Tags: evince

When launching evince on Ubuntu 19.10, it takes about 15 seconds before evince opens.  Dmesg output appears to be clean.  I disabled the apparmor profile as I'm having problems with it being on an overlayroot.  If I don't disable it, it won't even start.

The output from journalctl shows xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.service failed, but I'm not sure if that is directly related or just another problem.

I ran strace with evince; however, I am not seeing anything that stands out.  There are a bunch of no such file or directory errors.  I can post that if that will help.

strace:

```
strace -rTy -o /tmp/evince.2 evince




25.021775 write(11<anon_inode:[eventfd]>, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8 <0.000080>
```

The relative time for that call is 25seconds!

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 is EOL or *end-of-life* (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/01/23/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-23-2020/) thus off-topic on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) unless your question is specific to help moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Use a LTS or *long-term-support* release if you don't like *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months

Comment: Correction, I am on 19.10